# 2019.2.4f1 android il2cpp.exe did not run properly

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Как решить проблему со сборкой при **`IL2CPP`** в **Unity**?

Unity 2019.2.4f1

NDK: от юнити, установленный через **`Unity Hub`**

```
Failed running D:\2019.2.0f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe —convert-to-cpp —emit-null-checks —enable-array-bounds-check —dotnetprofile="unityaot" —compile-cpp —libil2cpp-static —platform="Android" —architecture="ARMv7" —configuration="Release" —outputpath="E:\unity_projects\New Unity Project (1)\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\armeabi-v7a\libil2cpp.so" —cachedirectory="E:\unity_projects\New Unity Project (1)\Assets\..\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a/il2cpp_cache" —additional-include-directories="D:/2019.2.0f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\bdwgc/include" —additional-include-directories="D:/2019.2.0f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\libil2cpp/include" —tool-chain-path="C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.4f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK" —profiler-report —map-file-parser=D:/2019.2.0f1/Editor/Data/Tools/MapFileParser/MapFileParser.exe —directory="E:/unity_projects/New Unity Project (1)/Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data/Managed" —generatedcppdir="E:/unity_projects/New Unity Project (1)/Temp/StagingArea/Il2Cpp/il2cppOutput"

stdout:
Building libil2cpp.so with AndroidToolChain
Output directory: E:\unity_projects\New Unity Project (1)\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\armeabi-v7a
Cache directory: E:\unity_projects\New Unity Project (1)\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache
il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. —-> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)
—- End of inner exception stack trace —-
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.RunWithResult[D,T](D[] data, Func`2 action)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.BuildAllCppFiles(IEnumerable`1 sourceFilesToCompile, IBuildStatisticsCollector statisticsCollector)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)
at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args)
at il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args)
at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<-—

---> (Inner Exception #1) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<-—

---> (Inner Exception #2) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<-—

---> (Inner Exception #3) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<-—

---> (Inner Exception #4) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<-—

---> (Inner Exception #5) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<-—

---> (Inner Exception #6) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<-—

---> (Inner Exception #7) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<-—

---> (Inner Exception #8) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<-—

---> (Inner Exception #9) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<-—

---> (Inner Exception #10) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<-—

---> (Inner Exception #11) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<-—

stderr:

Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. —-> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)
—- End of inner exception stack trace —-
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.RunWithResult[D,T](D[] data, Func`2 action)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.BuildAllCppFiles(IEnumerable`1 sourceFilesToCompile, IBuildStatisticsCollector statisticsCollector)
at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)
at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args)
at il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args)
at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunProgram(Program, String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:126)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunManagedProgram(String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase, Action`1) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:71)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:RunIl2CppWithArguments(List`1, Action`1, String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:502)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp(String, String, String, Boolean) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:483)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:Run() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:334)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils:RunIl2Cpp(String, String, IIl2CppPlatformProvider, Action`1, RuntimeClassRegistry) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:63)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

[image: Error]

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена. Нужно установить нормальный **`NDK`** - https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html **(r16)**