# Build - il2cpp.exe did not run properly, UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException, Unity 2019.4.28f1

Tags: c#, unity3d

> Доброго времени суток, у меня появилась проблема при "переносе" своего проекта в формат "WebGL"  с il2cpp.exe а так же с UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException.Подскажие пожалуйста как можно исправить их, **ПОШАГОВО**?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Exception: F:\Unity\2019.4.28f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/deploy/net471/il2cpp.exe did not run properly!
```

Comment: Вы ведь [уже задавали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1399380/220553) этот вопрос и вам там была дана ссылка по сути, на [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1021061/), где прямым текстом говорится `Нужно установить нормальный NDK`, ну и как бы, вы пробовали? Вот ваш вопрос сейчас звучит как "Ей народ, мне не хочется в этом разбираться, дайте мне ПОШАГОВУЮ инструкцию, где будет все разжевано" (из-за чего кстати и был закрыт тот вопрос), вот думаете это нормальный подход? Я нет.

Comment: EvgeniyZ лучше бы вы объяснили куда надо поместить "r16", не все рождаются вундеркиндами как вы. Поймите меня  правильно, я не с кем не хочу сориться. Но когда  ты заходишь на сайт созданный с целью: Помогать нуждающимся. И тебе пишут: "разбераешься сам". А ты ничего не понимаешь(из-за  недостатка  опыта). И просишь  инструкцию (пошаговую) чтобы  не наломать дров, и тебя выставляют как лентяя, который не хочет разбираться  сам а просит как вы там выразились: "где будет все разжевано" то это уже перебор.

Comment: Я считаю, что если вы не понимаете что либо, то значит вы высоко взяли. Нельзя за один день понять всю квантовую механику, стать ассом в интересующей сфере, нет! Но можно идти долго, небольшими шажками к своей цели. Тут не надо быть вундеркиндом, тут надо лишь потратить время на поиски и понимание того, что хотите. По этой причине, даже если вам разжуют все дословно, вы через пару шагов застопоритесь на другом и опять придете сюда требовать "разжевать" все. Вот вы придете на работу и скажете "я ничего не умею, но хочу 200к в месяц!", как должен отреагировать начальник на такое?

Comment: Касательно SO - Это не форум, где вы открываете топик и общаетесь, нет, SO это в первую очередь ресурс, где сообщество собирает вопросы и ответы на них, информация должна быть полезна не только автору вопроса, но и будущим читателям, которые найдут это через поиск. Я лично, пользы в вашем вопросе не вижу, да и если брать в расчет ссылку выше, то это дубликат, полноценный дубликат другого вопроса, на который уже есть ответ. Ну и не забываем, что у любого сообщества есть правила, а "Сделайте за меня", по правилам SO не хорошо. Хотите разобраться, не спихивайте на других свои задачи.

Comment: Не, ну вы преходите весь Рубикон . Если бы я вас попросил написать мне скрипт, например Ai бота, в котором учитываються все движения игрока, считываеться информация игрока и взависимости от действий выполняется  событие . То я бы понял ваше негодование. Но когда ты просишь объяснить "АЗЫ" и тебе говорят что ты взял слишком высоко.А я напомню  вам что если я смог сделать хотя бы какой-то  проект  то это значит что я не новичок.Вот скажите мне на милость,  место того чтобы  мне помочь, вы тратите моё и своё драгоценное время на обсуждения "какого же цвета небо синего или голубого".

Comment: Чтобы потом, мы разошлись  каждый со своим мнением?Поймите все мы люди, ни кто не идеален. Некоторые схватываю на лету а некоторым нужно  "Пережёвывать". Просто подскажите пожайлуста. Что нужно  делать дальше  после того как я установил к примеру (Windows  64- bit) .

Comment: Спорить не собираюсь, лишь попытался объяснить почему формулировка "ПОШАГОВО" неуместна, особенно капсом. Также я постарался объяснить почему закрыли предыдущий вопрос, чтобы вы не совершили эту ошибку вновь, но вместо того, чтоб написать нормально вопрос, попытаться найти решение самостоятельно, вы с наездом и все также требовательно упрашиваете решение. И с чего вы взяли, что il2cpp, это "азы"? Не каждый человек вообще знает про эту вещь, а это означает, что многим придется сначала изучить, а потом давать какие-либо советы. На этом, предлагаю закончить это все, желаю удачи в поисках решения.